# Displaying enum values together with a referenced class in Swagger using Swashbuckle

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swashbuckle

I am using Swashbuckle to generate Swagger output. On my model I the following property:

```cs
public FieldValue? MyProperty { get; set; }
```

FieldValue is a simple class that can hold an ID and a name:

```cs
public class FieldValue
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The numerical represenation of the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>1</example>
    public string Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The textual represenation of the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <example>SomeValue</example>
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Via some business logic in our code, a set of possible key-value pairs (ID and name) are mapped to this property.

Now, I would like to show all the possible values for `MyProperty` in the `enum` tag in my Swagger output. Using an implementation of `ISchemaFilter`, a custom attribute on the `MyProperty` property and using `allOf` instead of a simple `ref`, I have managed to add the values in my JSON output, see below. The reason for using `allOf` instead of just `ref` is that `ref` will overwrite all properties on the referencing schema. So, when I use `allOf` it keeps my `description` and `enum` fields in the document.

```json
{
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "FieldValue": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "Id": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "The numerical represenation of the value.",
                        "nullable": true,
                    },
                    "Name": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "The textual represenation of the value.",
                        "nullable": true,
                    }
                }
            },
            "MyProperty": {
                "enum": [
                    "1: EnumValue1",
                    "2: EnumValue2",
                    "3: EnumValue3"
                ],
                "allOf": [{
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FieldValue"
                    }
                ],
                "description": "Some description",
                "nullable": true
            }
    }
}
```

This does not show the enum-values in the Swagger UI, though. It does show the description.

**Is this Swagger doc valid? If not, how can I make it valid and display the enums for `MyProperty`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct representation of your use case is:

```json
  "MyProperty": {
    "enum": [
      {"Id": "1", "Name": "EnumValue1"},
      {"Id": "2", "Name": "EnumValue2"},
      {"Id": "3", "Name": "EnumValue3"}
    ],
    "allOf": [
       { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/FieldValue" }
     ],
    "description": "Some description",
    "nullable": true
  }
```

However, there's little to no tooling support for enums containing object literals. I suggest mentioning the possible `Id` and `Name` values in the `description` of the `MyProperty` property.